# How to detect that LazyVGrid's items get re-built?

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid, lazyvstack, onappear

In my app, `LazyVGrid` re-builds its contents multiple times. The number of items in the grid may vary or remain the same. Each time a particular item must be scrolled into view programmatically.
When the `LazyVGrid` first appears, an item can be scrolled into view using the `onAppear()` modifier.
Is there any way of detecting the moment when the `LazyVGrid` finishes re-building its items next time so that the grid can be safely scrolled?

Here is my code:

Grid

```
struct Grid: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading), count: viewModel.data.count / viewModel.rows)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                        let rowsCount = viewModel.rows
                        let columsCount = columns.count
                        ForEach((0..<rowsCount*columsCount), id: \.self) { index in
                            let data = viewModel.getData(for: index)
                            Text(data)
                                .id(index)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        // Scroll a particular item into view
                        let targetIndex = 32 // an arbitrary number for simplicity sake
                        scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(targetIndex, anchor: .top)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: geometry.size.width) { newWidth in
                        // Available screen width changed, for example on device rotation
                        // We need to re-build the grid to show more or less columns respectively.
                        // To achive this, we re-load data
                        // Problem: how to detect the moment when the LazyVGrid
                        // finishes re-building its items
                        // so that the grid can be safely scrolled?
                        let availableWidth = geometry.size.width
                        let columnsNumber = ScreenWidth.getNumberOfColumns(width: Int(availableWidth))
                        Task {
                                await viewModel.loadData(columnsNumber)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Helper enum to determine the number of columns to show in the grid

```
enum ScreenWidth: Int, CaseIterable {
    case extraSmall = 320
    case small      = 428
    case middle     = 568
    case large      = 667
    case extraLarge = 1080
    
    static func getNumberOfColumns(width: Int) -> Int {
        var screenWidth: ScreenWidth = .extraSmall
        for w in ScreenWidth.allCases {
            if width >= w.rawValue {
                screenWidth = w
            }
        }
        
        var numberOfColums: Int
        switch screenWidth {
        case .extraSmall:
            numberOfColums = 2
        case .small:
            numberOfColums = 3
        case .middle:
            numberOfColums = 4
        case .large:
            numberOfColums = 5
        case .extraLarge:
            numberOfColums = 8
        }
        return numberOfColums
    }
}
```

Simplified view model

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var data: [String] = []
    var rows: Int = 26
    
    init() {
        data = loadDataHelper(3)
    }
    
    func loadData(_ cols: Int) async {
        // emulating data loading latency
        await Task.sleep(UInt64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if let _self = self {
                _self.data = _self.loadDataHelper(cols)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadDataHelper(_ cols: Int) -> [String] {
        var dataGrid : [String] = []
        for index in 0..<rows*cols {
            dataGrid.append("\(index) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
        }
        return dataGrid
    }
    
    func getData(for index: Int) -> String {
        if (index > data.count-1){
            return "No data"
        }
        return data[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind providing the relevant part of code please?

Comment: @JanCássio yes, I should have done it when I posted my question. I've added code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions.

The first one is to put `LazyVGrid` inside `ForEach` with its range’s upper bound equal to an `Int` published variable incremented each time data is updated. In this way a new instance of `LazyVGrid` is created on each update so we can make use of `LazyVGrid`’s `onAppear` method to do some initialization work, in this case scroll a particular item into view.

Here is how it can be implemented:

```
struct Grid: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading), count: viewModel.data.count / viewModel.rows)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                    ForEach((viewModel.dataIndex-1..<viewModel.dataIndex), id: \.self) { dataIndex in
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                            let rowsCount = viewModel.rows
                            let columsCount = columns.count
                            ForEach((0..<rowsCount*columsCount), id: \.self) { index in
                                let data = viewModel.getData(for: index)
                                Text(data)
                                    .id(index)
                            }
                        }
                        .id(1000 + dataIndex)
                        .onAppear {
                            print("LazyVGrid, onAppear, #\(dataIndex)")
                            let targetItem = 32 // arbitrary number
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                                scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(targetItem, anchor: .top)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .onAppear {
                load(availableWidth: geometry.size.width)
            }
            .onChange(of: geometry.size.width) { newWidth in
                // Available screen width changed.
                // We need to re-build the grid to show more or less columns respectively.
                // To achive this, we re-load data.
                load(availableWidth: geometry.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func load(availableWidth: CGFloat){
        let columnsNumber = ScreenWidth.getNumberOfColumns(width: Int(availableWidth))
        Task {
            await viewModel.loadData(columnsNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    /*@Published*/ private(set) var data: [String] = []
    @Published private(set) var dataIndex = 0
    var rows: Int = 46 // arbitrary number
    
    func loadData(_ cols: Int) async {
        let newData = loadDataHelper(cols)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if let _self = self {
                _self.data = newData
                _self.dataIndex += 1 
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadDataHelper(_ cols: Int) -> [String] {
        var dataGrid : [String] = []
        for index in 0..<rows*cols {
            dataGrid.append("\(index) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
        }
        return dataGrid
    }
}
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------**

The second approach is based on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878281/1249407) proposed by @NewDev.

The idea is to track grid items' "rendered" status and fire a callback once they have appeared after the grid re-built its contents in response to viewmodel's data change.

`RenderModifier` keeps track of grid item's "rendered" status using `PreferenceKey` to collect data.
The `.onAppear()` modifier is used to set "rendered" status while the `.onDisappear()` modifier is used to reset the status.

```
struct RenderedPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Int = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {
        value = value + nextValue() // sum all those that remain to-be-rendered
    }
}

struct RenderModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var toBeRendered = 1
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .preference(key: RenderedPreferenceKey.self, value: toBeRendered)
            .onAppear { toBeRendered = 0 }
            .onDisappear { /*reset*/ toBeRendered = 1 }
    }
}
```

Convenience methods on View:

```
extension View {
    func trackRendering() -> some View {
        self.modifier(RenderModifier())
    }

    func onRendered(_ perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.onPreferenceChange(RenderedPreferenceKey.self) { toBeRendered in
           // Invoke the callback only when all tracked statuses have been set to 0,
           // which happens when all of their .onAppear() modifiers are called
           if toBeRendered == 0 { perform() }
        }
    }
}
```

Before loading new data the view model clears its current data to make the grid remove its contents. This is necessary for the `.onDisappear()` modifiers to get called on grid items.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var data: [String] = []
    var dataLoadedFlag: Bool = false
    var rows: Int = 46 // arbitrary number
    
    func loadData(_ cols: Int) async {
        // Clear data to make the grid remove its items.
        // This is necessary for the .onDisappear() modifier to get called on grid items.
        if !data.isEmpty {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                if let _self = self {
                    _self.data = []
                }
            }
            // A short pause is necessary for a grid to have time to remove its items.
            // This is crucial for scrolling grid for a specific item.
            await Task.sleep(UInt64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        }

        let newData = loadDataHelper(cols)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if let _self = self {
                _self.dataLoadedFlag = true
                _self.data = newData
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadDataHelper(_ cols: Int) -> [String] {
        var dataGrid : [String] = []
        for index in 0..<rows*cols {
            dataGrid.append("\(index) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
        }
        return dataGrid
    }
    
    func getData(for index: Int) -> String {
        if (index > data.count-1){
            return "No data"
        }
        return data[index]
    }
}
```

An example of usage of the `trackRendering()` and `onRendered()` functions:

```
struct Grid: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading), count: viewModel.data.count / viewModel.rows)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                        let rowsCount = viewModel.rows
                        let columsCount = columns.count
                        ForEach((0..<rowsCount*columsCount), id: \.self) { index in
                            let data = viewModel.getData(for: index)
                            Text(data)
                                .id(index)
                                // set RenderModifier
                                .trackRendering()
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        load(availableWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: geometry.size.width) { newWidth in
                        // Available screen width changed.
                        // We need to re-build the grid to show more or less columns respectively.
                        // To achive this, we re-load data.
                        load(availableWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                    .onRendered {
                        // do scrolling only if data was loaded,
                        // that is the grid was re-built
                        if viewModel.dataLoadedFlag {
                            /*reset*/ viewModel.dataLoadedFlag = false
                            let targetItem = 32 // arbitrary number
                            scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(targetItem, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func load(availableWidth: CGFloat){
        let columnsNumber = ScreenWidth.getNumberOfColumns(width: Int(availableWidth))
        Task {
            await viewModel.loadData(columnsNumber)
        }
    }
}
```